# drivers for ati 3000 graphics

Tags: drivers, ati, radeon, 3d

I am currently using a system with integrated mother board graphics of Radeon 3000 graphics, and I am facing a severe problem of Ubuntu's INCOMPATIBILITY with 3d graphics on Chrome. For example, Chrome web store apps like Biodigital Human 3D. When I launch the app it first checks the compatibility and says as follows:

> BioDigital Human
>
> Looks like your computer doesn't support the 3D Graphics required by
> the Human. It's probably because it's built using WebGL, which
> requires a newer computer.
>
> If you'd like updates as we continue improving the system, please join
> our email list.
>
> You can also learn more about your options and the technical
> requirements here

When I was using Windows 7 on this computer the app was supported. Is there any driver missing in my system?
I think it's all about the drivers can anyone help me to get rid of this problem please?

Comment: The Additional Drivers program does not show any drivers for agha rehan abbas computer.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Radeon HD3000 is a R600 GPU which should be [supported by the open source drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Your question will be clearer if you could post the output of lspci | grep VGA

Comment: how to get it done

Comment: @agharehanabbas: You've to open a terminal and execute this command: `sudo lspci | grep VGA`. Edit your question and post your output.. :)

Comment: the thing is that i have removed ubuntu from my pc and installed windows 7 but when i try to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 and click the option to install it alongside ubuntu my system restarts and the dvd from which i am installing ubuntu is ejected out can anyone help me to get out of this issue

Comment: @agharehanabbas Uhhh.. that seems to be completely unrelated to the problem you have stated above. You should probably ask a new question about it(after researching well about the issue yourself).

Comment: i have asked a question on this topic but no one answered it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to additional drivers tab in software & updates.
Check for any drivers. If there are allow them or install them.

Try these sites also:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1203437